# how to fix IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer.reset

Tags: android, service, media-player, reset

i have mediaPlayer in Service with audioTales. whan i press startService first time - it works great. but if i'll stopService and than start egain - there are  IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer.reset
in my case i call .reset() before .release() so this is not the reason of crash...

i am new in android developing, so please dont be very strickt... )

here is catlog:

```
03-07 21:54:40.521  18845-18845/ua.andriyantonov.tales E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service ua.andriyantonov.tales.TalePlay_Service: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1331)
            at ua.andriyantonov.tales.TalePlay_Service.onCreate(TalePlay_Service.java:69)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2367)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:134)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is Service.class:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        bufferIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_BUFFER);
        seekIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        aDialogIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ADIALOG);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mPlayer.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){

        /**set up receiver for seekBar change and PlayResume btns*/
        getApplication().registerReceiver(seekBarChangedBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(TaleActivity_Audio.BROADCAST_SEEKBAR));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplication()).registerReceiver(switchPlayPauseBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(TaleActivity_Audio.BROADCAST_switchPlayStatus));

        initNotification();

        /** Manage incomingphone calls during playback
        *     public static final String BROADCAST_BUFFER = "ua.andriyantonov.tales.broadcastbuffer";
        e mp on incoming
        * Resume on hangup  */
        telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        /** register the listener with telephony manager */


        phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
            switch (state){
                case  TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    if (mPlayer!=null){
                    pauseTaleAudio();
                    isPausedInCall=true;
                    }
                    break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        /** need to make alertDialog and ask "do you want to resume?"  */
                        if (mPlayer!=null){
                        if (isPausedInCall){
                        isPausedInCall=false;
                            pauseTaleAudio();
                            sendAfterCallADialogBroadcast();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
            }
            }
                };
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        /**check if the tale was already downloaded and mp3 file existed
         * if it was - use mp3 from storage
         * if not - upload from cloudService*/
        UpdateTalesData.loadTalesData(getApplicationContext());
        talePosition=UpdateTalesData.talePosition;
        if (UpdateTalesData.checkTaleExist.exists()){
            dataSource= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+"/"+
                    getResources().getString(R.string.mainAudioTale_name)+talePosition+".mp3";
        } else {
            dataSource=UpdateTalesData.data_HTTP;
        }

        /** set data source for player and get prepared*/
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(dataSource);
                /** send message to activity to progress uploading dialog*/
                mPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IllegalStateException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /** show buffering progress bar if playing online*/
        if (!UpdateTalesData.checkTaleExist.exists()){
            sendBufferingBroadcast();
        }

                /** set up seekbar handler*/
                setupHandler();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mPlayer!=null){
            if (mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
            mPlayer.release();
        }
        stopSelf();
        if (phoneStateListener!=null){
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
        }

        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        cancelNotification();
        getApplication().unregisterReceiver(seekBarChangedBroadcastReceiver);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(switchPlayPauseBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) { }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        switch (what){
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                Toast.makeText(this,"MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK" +extra,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                Toast.makeText(this,"MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED" +extra,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                Toast.makeText(this,"MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN" +extra,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        sendBufferCompleteBroadcast();
        playTaleAudio();
    }

    public void playTaleAudio(){
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }
    public void pauseTaleAudio(){
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    private void setupHandler(){
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 0);
    }
    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LogTaleAudioPosition();
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }
    };

    private void LogTaleAudioPosition(){
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            taleAudioPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            taleAudioMaxDuration = mPlayer.getDuration();
            seekIntent.putExtra("counter",String.valueOf(taleAudioPosition));
            seekIntent.putExtra("audioMax",String .valueOf(taleAudioMaxDuration));
            seekIntent.putExtra("song_ended",String .valueOf(audioTaleEnded));
            String maxDurationText = convertFormat(taleAudioMaxDuration);
            seekIntent.putExtra("audioMaxText",maxDurationText);
            String currTimePosText = convertFormat(taleAudioPosition);
            seekIntent.putExtra("currTimePosText",currTimePosText);
           sendBroadcast(seekIntent);
        }
    }

    public String convertFormat(long miliSeconds){
        long s = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(miliSeconds)%60;
        long m = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(miliSeconds)%60;
        return String .format("%02d:%02d",m,s);
    }

    /** receive player position (play or pause) if it has been changed by the user in fragment*/
    private BroadcastReceiver switchPlayPauseBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switchPlayPause(intent);
        }
    };
    public void switchPlayPause(Intent intent){
        switchPlayStatus = intent.getIntExtra("switchPlayStatus",-1);
        if (switchPlayStatus==1){
            pauseTaleAudio();
        } else if (switchPlayStatus==2){
            playTaleAudio();
        }
    }

    /** receive seekbar position if it has been changed by the user in fragment*/
    private BroadcastReceiver seekBarChangedBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateSeekBarPosition(intent);
        }
    };
    public void updateSeekBarPosition(Intent intent){
        int seekPos = intent.getIntExtra("seekPos",0);
        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
            mPlayer.seekTo(seekPos);
            setupHandler();
        }
    }

    /** send message to activity that audio is being prepared and buffering started*/
    public void sendBufferingBroadcast(){
        bufferIntent.putExtra("buffering","1");
        sendBroadcast(bufferIntent);
    }

    /** send message to activity that audio is prepared and ready to start playing*/
    public void sendBufferCompleteBroadcast(){
        bufferIntent.putExtra("buffering","0");
        sendBroadcast(bufferIntent);
    }

    /** send message to activity that audio is prepared and ready to start playing*/
    public void sendAfterCallADialogBroadcast(){
        aDialogIntent.putExtra("aDialogIntent","1");
        sendBroadcast(aDialogIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stopSelf();
        audioTaleEnded=1;
        seekIntent.putExtra("song_ended",String .valueOf(audioTaleEnded));
        sendBroadcast(seekIntent);
        UpdateTalesData.saveTalesIntData(context,"isPlaying",UpdateTalesData.isPlaying=0);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            playTaleAudio();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    private void initNotification(){
        CharSequence tikerText = getResources().getString(R.string.tickerText);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,tikerText,System.currentTimeMillis());
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence contentTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.contentTitle);
        CharSequence contentText = UpdateTalesData.taleName;
        Intent notifIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
        notifIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notifIntent.putExtra("showAudioFrag",true);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,notifIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context,contentTitle,contentText,contentIntent);
        Log.d("", "" + notifIntent.getExtras());
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private void cancelNotification(){
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer would be to remove `mPlayer.reset();` from the `onCreate()` method of the `Service`. Why are you doing that anyway? You haven't started using the `MediaPlayer` at that stage so why do you think you need to reset it?

Comment: even if i put mPlayer.reset(); to onStartCommand the error still present...

Comment: But why are you calling `reset()`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: reset() is needed to clear mediaPlayer, if i understand documentation correctly.

Comment: MediaPlayer API is absolutely terrible. I've made a POC where I can test each MediaPlayer functions in different order, and lord it is hard to find a way not to crash it. Not to say that everything depends on states that just doesn't actually exist anywhere.

Comment: In my case, basically, to have the player re-usable once on error or on completed, I had to explicitely stop() and start() before being able to make a reset() on the player, then from there, I had to re-do all the instanciation of the player - dispose / new mediaplayer() - with the setSurface, then a prepare(). Not very natural.

Answer (score 7):

in my case the solution was next:

1. delete `mPlayer.reset();` from `onCreate`;
2. in `onDestroy()` change `mPlayer.release();` to `mPlayer.reset();`

and after this i havent IllegalStateException.

i hope my case and solution will help someone )